# Conditions in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, conditional-statements

What's the correct way to use operations such as `$not` or `$ne` with complex values? I mean values, which are also computed with some operations. I've tried `{$not: {$and: [{field1: 'a'}, {field2: 'b'}]}}` and `{$not: [{$and: [{field1: 'a'}, {field2: 'b'}]}]}`, but none of them seem to work correctly. The same with `$ne`: `{$ne: [field1, field2]}`. The documentation shows their usage examples as `field1: {$not: {$gt: 5}}`, and it's nice for so simple cases, but how to deal with more complex ones?

If it makes a difference, I want to use them in a `$match` clause of the aggregation framework, not just in a `find()`.

UPD:

For example, i'd want to run such query: `db.test.aggregate({$match: {$not: {$and: [{f1: 'a'}, {f2: 'b'}]}}})`, but it give error "invalid operator: $and" (the same code without `$not` works). To test that query insert documents before: `db.test.insert({f1:'a', f2:'b'}); db.test.insert({f1:'b', f2:'c'})`.

Comment: It would help if you updated your question to include some example docs, the results you expect from your queries, and what your attempts return instead.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: docs can be found and MongoDB website, e.g. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/not/ for `$not`. Included query example.

Comment: Sorry, I mean example MongoDB collection document objects that you're trying to execute this query over.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: added this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$not` and `$ne` are field-specific operators, so you can't apply them to a multi-field query operation.  I don't think you can construct a generalized 'negative' query like you're trying to do.

Instead, you'd need to invert your logic field by field to use a query like:

```js
db.test.aggregate({$match: {$or: [{f1: {$ne: 'a'}}, {f2: {$ne: 'b'}}]}})
```

Comment: I'm very surprised that it's unsupported. But why is so? Does it make any sense, or just not implemented yet?

Comment: @chersanya I think it makes sense, but just isn't implemented.